# I am a non-EU Citizen. If I get a work permit from Malta, can my wife travel with me and what is required for her to stay with me?

Tags: eu, family, non-residents, pakistani-citizen, malta

What is the requirement to get my non-EU house-wife with me to Malta? if i obtain a work permit of Computer Engineer as a non EU national.

If she is not given spouse visa at the time of joining, how much time will it take to let her come to Malta on long term spouse visa?

We both are Pakistani citizens.

Answer (score 2):

As a non-eu/eec citizen with a valid work permit in Malta, under EU law you are entitled to apply for the family reunification visa for your wife.

In order to do this, then you must already be living in Malta before you apply for a visa for her.
You must meet the requirements set out under Maltese law which includes providing evidence of your marital status, being over 21, already living and working in Malta with a valid work and residence permit valid for at least 1 year, earning at least average salary + 20% for every family member wishing to join, having accommodation which is suitable for your family, sickness insurance.

You then apply, pay the fees, and a decision is made.  Your wife is then issued a visa and can travel to Malta to join you where she will be able to live and work there, and have access to education to the same level as you can.

There are no details upon the average processing times, but the law states that it must not take longer than 9 months to make a decision!  If I was you, I would plan on it taking 3 - 6 months.

More details can be found here:
https://identitymalta.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/Checklist-for-TCNs-applying-for-the-Family-Reunification-status.pdf

https://www.expat-quotes.com/guides/malta/visas-and-permits/residence-permits-non-eu-or-third-country-nationals.htm

http://justiceservices.gov.mt/DownloadDocument.aspx?app=lom&itemid=9561&l=1

Comment: (+1) A lot of valuable info but how is that related to EU law?

Comment: OK, I found it in the third link, it's directive 2003/86/EC.

Comment: @Relaxed Yes, I did not quote the EU law.  This is because the EU law sets down that this must be done, but national law sets the individual requirements per country, and hence that is more specific and relevant for the OP.

Comment: Yes, it was more curiosity on my part, I didn't realize EU law covered this to such an extent.